# Launch Python from Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

This is a noob question but I can't seem to figure out. When I try to launch Python from PowerShell, it runs in PowerShell. How do I launch Python from Powershell and have it run in a new window?

(For instance, if i type "Notepad" and hit enter then Notepad pops up in a new window.)

So I launch PowerShell and then enter `PS C:\Users\Michael> Python` . This opens it up in Powershell, but how do I open it up in a new window?

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I searched through the forum but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do -

```
Invoke-Item /path/to/python.exe
```

You will need to give the full path there. Exanple , in my case it is -

```
Invoke-Item C:\Python34\python.exe
```