# Python 2 and 3 in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have both versions on my PC because I'm working through different tutorials, (I'm still a noob). I've seen a couple of similar questions on here, but nothing specific to Powershell.

When I run **python** in Powershell it brings up 2.7, but how do I specify that I want Python 3? Are there other issues that I need to be aware of? For example when running scripts from notepad++?

Comment: Have you tried `python3` ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quick. I tried that, but it comes back with an error.

Comment: Check your path variable and see what the python bin path order is. I bet your python 2.7 will be listed first. You can specify the full path to python.exe to make sure you are running the correct version, or change your system path environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it could be the trick. Are there any resources I could look at to help me do this?

Comment: Use `#! python3` shebang? Run `py -3`?

Comment: Yay! Thanks wOxxOm! `py -3` worked, and I can use `py -2` for the v2. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command "py" (if v2 is the default) or "py -2" should launch Python 2.7, "py -3" should launch Python 3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328713/6683985) for the details.

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371084/6683985) as well. It might be helpful.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/6683985) will help you check the current version you are using, if you desire to change that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328713/6683985).

[Should you want to pop out of the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237640/6683985).

Cheers and have fun with Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python3 [via Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/python3), AFAIK it will bring `python3` command into your realm. Do not forget to uninstall previously installed Python3 before it.

Also, you may try to create alias for Python3, see Microsoft [doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176913.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I was about to do that, but [Chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-coreteampackages/issues/106) seems to no longer be trusted, so I'm hesitant. I'd like to create an alias, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to run Python 3 in the first place.